# Determine if user logged in at work or at home

Tags: windows-10, login, event-log

I have a corporate laptop with Windows 10 (1709). Since COVID, I work from home and only very rarely in the office. Working from home means I log in without a connection to the company (cached credentials I imagine)

I'd now like to find out the days I actually worked in the office. My idea is that somewhere in the event logs I might find something related (successful logins with non-cached credentials or something similar).

Searching the internet I found events, but none seem to match my idea.

Which event codes may help in this case?

Edit: Typo

Comment: You can log in off-domain at home, at work, in a coffee shop on the way to work, so that measurement won't help much. I do not know of any other like measurement. Keep a log. I have done that in 2 decades of personal business consulting.

Comment: May be true but doesn't apply: I only want to know the dates I actually log in _at work_.
I bet there is something in the events I could use, I have just not figured it out yet.

Comment: This entirely depends if those events are being recorded. Best keep the activities like this limited to a system administrators.

Comment: @Ramhound: Wich event IDs would that be, so I can check if they are recorded or not?